# AlertDialog doesn't show in catch block

Tags: android, try-catch, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to parse some XML data from the web. Most of the time, the XML's are clean and well displayed in my app. This works perfectly. I also want to build in some security, so the app doesn't crash when there's a bad XML.

So when an XML couldn't get parsed it hops to my catch block where I proceed this:

```
try {
            Log.e("in try", "try");
            /* Create a URL we want to load some xml-data from. */
            URL url = new URL("http://172.21.150.140:80/scripts/cgiip.exe/WService=brAccentBe/Android/getVacatureDetails.html?Vacid=" + vacaid + "&Kantoorid=" + kantoorid);

            System.out.println("Url " + url);
            /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

            /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/ 
            vacatureDetailsWebservice vs = new vacatureDetailsWebservice();
            xr.setContentHandler(vs);

            /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */
            xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            /* Parsing has finished. */

            /* Our ExampleHandler now provides the parsed data to us. */
            vaca = vs.getVacatures();


        }    
 catch (Exception e) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(JobDetails.this);
            builder.setTitle("Fout in XML");
            builder.setMessage("Er is een fout opgetreden in de data. Probeer het later nog eens");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            }); 
            builder.create().show();
        }
```

But the Dialog won't show, the class continues to run and gets other exceptions because XML isn't parsed. This method is called in onCreate.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the code that should throw the exception you're trying to catch.

Comment: @Ben Williams, I've added it.

Comment: That looks okay at first glance; could you please add an example of the XML that should fail but passes through without throwing an exception?  Is it possible your custom contenthandler is consuming the errors instead of re-throwing them?

Comment: There you go. The problems occur in the Omschrijving tag. There are Start of Headers there, which he can't get around.

Comment: can you send error code and your logcat detail

Comment: I've added LogCat for you, but the nullpointerException is caused by the XML that isn't parsed, so the object where the XML is saved to, is null. It just won't show the AlertDialog.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below things may be it will work but not sure...

boolean bol = false;

try{

// your code

}
catch (Exception e) {

bol = true;

}

```
     if (bol){

       final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Fout in XML");
        builder.setMessage("Er is een fout opgetreden in de data. Probeer het later nog eens");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        }); 
        builder.create().show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but the app still crashes.

Comment: can you check i think your tag <diploma1> inside numeric so it may be occur problem. please check it. same as other tag..

Comment: I know why it crashes, but I want to catch crashes so it just shows alert dialog and returns to some other activity.